# Mysql server remove/install problem - horribily broken

Tags: debian, mysql, dpkg

I'm having the same issue as Ken did on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7691/removing-broken-packages) post.

And I did pretty much what Ken did except to different packages. Now, I'm stuck with unclean hooks. I've detailed my problem [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4924128#post4924128) and the attempts I've made so far. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Note: If cross referencing is prohibited I'm willing to re-post them here although I'm **not** associated with the site I'm referencing to.

Comment: try `apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1`

Comment: Wow ... Thanks. I thought that mysql-server is a meta package for current version mysql-server-5.1 but I guess it doesn't work the same way. Thanks again. I got it working.

Comment: @ManulaWaidyanatha: Care to post that comment as an answer? ;-)

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Done.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql-server` is a meta package. You have to remove `mysql-server-5.1`

`apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1`